# How can I find the value of the "Visual Effects" setting using the command line?

Tags: 10.04, gnome, command-line, compiz

On 10.04 (and other versions, but I am asking about 10.04), going to
 *System ➜ Preferences ➜ Appearance* and selecting the *Visual Effects* tab shows possible values of *None*, *Normal*, and *Extra*. How can I query from the command line what the current setting is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. If you are using GNOME, then there is excellent `gconftool` command.

Try

```
gconftool --get /desktop/gnome/session/required_components/windowmanager
```

It'll return `metacity` when setting is "None" and `compiz` for "Normal". At least in my Ubuntu 10.10 only difference between "Normal" and "Extra" was "wobbly" in plugins list.

Try

```
gconftool --get /apps/compiz/general/allscreens/options/active_plugins
```

to get list of plugins. Output should be something like

> [core,ccp,move,resize,place,decoration,dbus,mousepoll,gnomecompat,png,svg,imgjpeg,text,commands,neg,wall,snap,animation,scale,scaleaddon,expo,staticswitcher,regex,resizeinfo,workarounds,ezoom,vpswitch,fade,session,shift,wobbly]

for "Extra" visual effects.

Comment: Thanks! Does one of those items in the "Extra" list correspond specifically to translucency/transparency?

Comment: It would be "obs" in that list. In compizconfig it's called Opacity, Brightness, and Saturation.

Comment: For Ubuntu 10.04.3, it's still 'metacity' for None, but 'gnome-wm' for Normal and Extra.